# vb.net export control container to pdf

Tags: vb.net, pdf, charts, pdf-generation

Im working in a new vb.net project in which i have to show different graphic in a windows. All this graphics are generated reading an xml file.

The program have to process all the xml files inside a directory, generate the graphics and then export or save all the graphics into a PDF file.

My question is, is there a way i can export a container with all its controls inside into pdf file, or can you recommend me a way to export files into pdf using vb.net, that can handle charts and text?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After looking for several ways to approach this. I found the iTextSharpLibrary. This do not converts all the items inside a container into a pdf directly; but have an easy API to create PDF files and add images and much more.

Visit and Download it at http://sourceforge.net/projects/itextsharp/